# DataGridView and SqlDataAdapter not updating correctly

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource, sqldataadapter

I've been looking around a lot and I cannot figure out where this problem is coming from. What's happening is that I have a datagridview using a BindingSource, SqlDataAdapter, SqlCommandBuilder, and a DataTable. The datagridview is populated with a simple select query (which only uses one table from the MSSQL Server DB). I want to be able to edit things in this table. Right now, editing works, but not the way it should. I would think that I would be able to edit a cell, hit enter, and have the changes committed to the database. What actually happens, is that the changes do not appear until I finish editing a second cell. Anyone know what I'm overlooking here? Thanks!

Here is the relevant code in the .cs file:

```
public partial class CheckIn : Form
{

    private BindingSource searchDGVBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    private SqlDataAdapter searchDGVDataAdapter;
    private SqlCommandBuilder searchDGVSqlCommandBuilder;
    private DataTable  searchDGVDataTable;


    public CheckIn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(CheckIn_Load);
    }

    private void CheckIn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchDGV.DataSource = searchDGVBindingSource;
        searchDGVDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);
        searchDGVSqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(searchDGVDataAdapter);
        searchDGVDataTable = new DataTable();
        searchDGVDataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        searchDGVDataAdapter.Fill(searchDGVDataTable);
        searchDGVBindingSource.DataSource = searchDGVDataTable;

        searchDGV.AutoResizeColumns();
    }

    private void searchGridView_RowEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        searchDGVDataAdapter.Update(searchDGVDataTable);
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant code from the .Designer.cs file:

```
        // 
        // searchDGV
        // 
        this.searchDGV.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.searchDGV.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.searchDGV.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.searchDGV.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.searchDGV.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 250);
        this.searchDGV.MultiSelect = false;
        this.searchDGV.Name = "searchDGV";
        this.searchDGV.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.searchDGV.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(619, 150);
        this.searchDGV.TabIndex = 7;
        this.searchDGV.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.searchGridView_CellClick);
        this.searchDGV.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.searchGridView_RowEndEdit);
```

Comment: Any reason you have the `CellEndEdit` event being handled by a method named `searchGridView_RowEndEdit` ?

Comment: I just haven't renamed the searchGridView_RowEndEdit method to something more appropriate. I had named it that because I was trying a different approach.

Comment: Have you validated that the changes you are performing are actually valid?

Comment: If you put breakpoint in your event handler, does it stop there when you leave first cell?

Comment: By valid changes do you mean valid to the database? If so then yes, they are valid. All I'm doing in this case is changing a name -- just adding an extra letter just as a simple test.

Comment: Also, yes the debugger stops at the breakpoint in the event handler function when leaving the first cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `searchDGVBindingSource.EndEdit()` in your event handler and it will work:

```
private void searchGridView_RowEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    searchDGVBindingSource.EndEdit();
    searchDGVDataAdapter.Update(searchDGVDataTable);
}
```

Check [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit.aspx) for `BindingSource.EndEdit()` to learn more about it.

Comment: That did the trick! I've spent a fair amount of time trying to track this down, thank you!